# Spark monitoring with Prometheus on yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus

How can I get metrics for the two jobs running on same node or localhost ona single port so that Prometheus can scrape those metrics without giving several targets. Is there any approach?

I have tried using jmx exporter but we need to pass port on that and once a job started on a particular port when I am running another job using that same port only it gives me error javaagent already in use and if we change the port it will run the job but problem here is for thousand of jobs we can't add thousand of ports in the targets in Prometheus.yml manually.